# Restricting Kernel Density Estimate to n-sided polygon

Tags: density-function, kernel-smoothing, multivariate-distribution

Given some arbitrarily distributed data, in this case data generated by two normal distributions,

$\mathcal{N_1}(\mu_1, \Sigma_1)$ and $\mathcal{N_2}(\mu_2, \Sigma_2)$ where $\mu_1 = \begin{bmatrix}0 & 0\end{bmatrix}^T, \Sigma_1 = \begin{bmatrix}10 & 0 \\ 0 & 100\end{bmatrix}$ and $\mu_2 = \begin{bmatrix}20 & 10\end{bmatrix}^T, \Sigma_2 = \begin{bmatrix}45 & 0 \\ 0 & 35\end{bmatrix}$

A multivariate KDE is computed, in this case using Python and [KDEpy](https://github.com/tommyod/KDEpy/), with a Gaussian kernel and bandwidth $3I$. An arbitrary n-sided polygon is given, which can be considered as a sequence of piece-wise linear segments. The particular polygon is defined by the tuples $[(-10, -10), (22, 3), (30, 27), (-12, 30), (-20, 0)]$.

[image: KDE with polygonal boundary]

My question is then as follows: **Is it possible to perform boundary correction to adhere towards such an arbitrary polygon?** I would like to compute the KDE such that the PDF is contained within the polygon, without necessarily "filling" it up completely.

I'm aware that for the 1D case and "simple" geometries, boundary correction can be achieved by techniques such as [mirroring the data](https://kdepy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples.html#boundary-correction-using-mirroring). However, I'm unsure what is classified a simple geometries. For 2D and higher dimensions, I have seen boundary correction can be achieved by analytical boundaries described by shapes such circles or ellipses.

Comment: Sure it's possible.  I have performed this correction simply through truncation: zero out the tails beyond the polygon and renormalize the remainder.  This is not universally applicable, though: whether it makes sense depends on what you are using your KDE for.

Comment: Would you clarify as to what "without necessarily 'filling' it up completely" means?  And what @whuber suggests is exactly what one would do if you had the "true" bivariate density function.

Comment: @whuber Thank you for your comment. Should the proposed truncation occur at the distribution of each data point? One thing to mention is that my is not necessarily described by n normal distributions, this detail was included if someone wanted to recreate the above plots.

Comment: @Jimb Thank you for your comment. My comment regarding "filling" refers to that the polygon should simply act as a boundary, It is not the intention that the KDE is re-distributed to fit the entire shape. The polygon is simply a bound on the feasible 2D states. I apologise if this is worded poorly.

Comment: I have edited the original post to state that the given data is not necessarily normally distributed.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by the "distribution of each data point."  Treat the KDE as a distribution and pay no attention to its internal structure.

Comment: Hi @whuber, thanks for your follow up comment. I really appreciate your feedback. I apologise for my lack of clarity, I misunderstood part of the concept. I have zero'ed the densities in the grid which lie outside the polygon. Is it sufficient to compute the integral of this new updated grid and renormalize using this factor, or does it usually take place differently? Here's an updated figure post zeroing the tails, pre renormalization https://i.imgur.com/M9sFT31.png

Comment: Yes, that sounds like the correct grid operation.  Once again, I am assuming you are trying to truncate the estimated distribution to the polygon rather than performing some other operation.

Comment: @whuber based on your feedback I have managed to re-normalize it and achieve the desired results. One final question, given this truncated estimate, how would one go about sampling it? In the non-truncated case, I would uniformly select a data point and sample the kernel function at said location. However, doing so in the truncated case, isn't there a risk of sampling outside the polygon? If the selected point lies close to the boundary, and the bandwidth of the kernel causes it to exceed the bounds.

Comment: If you mean sampling *in proportion to the estimated density,* see https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/147342/664.  If you just want *uniform* sampling, see the simpler procedures at https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/17255 and https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/80904.

Comment: Sorry, I'm slow so I don't understand @whuber's first link and it's relationship to sampling from the truncated distribution.  If you want a random sample from the truncated distribution, just sample from the original estimated distribution and toss any points that fall outside the polygon.  Point-in-polygon routines are very fast and I can't imagine there would be a substantial increase in computation time even if  you were tossing 50% of the sample points. Just fix the desired sample size and keep sampling until you get that sample size that are in the polygon.

Comment: @JimB The contour plot indicates the KDE is represented as a grid of densities.  The sampling method to use must rely on that grid as input: there is no point-in-polygon problem in evidence.

Comment: @whuber I'm not trying to be argumentative but I guess I'm just being thick.  A grid of points (x,y, and density) is usually a type of input to a contour function and has nothing to do with a grid on the ground.  But I see the OP belongs to a GIS StackExchange group so maybe "grid" (both of you mention in the comments) is standard terminology in that subject matter which I know little about.  I don't see a grid used to develop a contour to limit the resolution of a random data point.

Comment: @Jim Almost always, a KDE is generated as a mixture of distributions centered at points on a regular grid.  You can be virtually certain that the contour map on the left represents such a grid as developed from the original point data on the right.

Comment: I'm interested in the $k$-dimensional polytope case.